# jQuery Draggable Input Elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make form elements draggable using jQuery UI. For example, buttons, checkboxes, textfields, etc. So far I have had no luck. Do you have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe 3 years too late but you could dispatch event and use following snippet for a more expected behaviour:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFHd6/52/)

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).data('preventBehaviour', true);
    }
});
$(".draggable").find(":input").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    var mdown = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
        screenX: e.screenX,
        screenY: e.screenY,
        clientX: e.clientX,
        clientY: e.clientY,
        view: window
    });
    $(this).closest('.draggable')[0].dispatchEvent(mdown);
}).on('click', function (e) {
    var $draggable = $(this).closest('.draggable');
    if ($draggable.data("preventBehaviour")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $draggable.data("preventBehaviour", false)
    }
});
```

Comment: `initMouseEvent` is deprecated - any idea what's replacing it?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob Thx for the feedback. I have updated answer using `MouseEvent()`  constructor

Comment: Thanks, it's a brilliant solution to the problem,

Comment: Elegant! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The trick consists to put a transparent div over the inputs elements :

```
div div{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div input{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
<div><div>&nbsp;</div><input type="text" value="..." disabled="true"/></div>
$('body>div').draggable();
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I needed to display form inputs, make them draggable and unusable without changing their appearance for a WYSIWYG. Can't believe I didn't think of this simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think this best suits your requirements :) Its draggable + resizable on input element, yet you don't lose their nature to be editable.

```
$(function(){
    $('.draggable').draggable().resizable();
});
```

Here's my solution for you: [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roylee0704/7WVwN/).

Answer (score 2):

Well input elements need to be editable, so making them ***draggable*** would make them uneditable.

Wrap them in a `<span>` or a `<div>`, and **I strongly suggest you use a [handle](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle)**.

Comment: Yea but what if you don't want the input's editable.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to put it in wrapper and set this CSS for the input:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

You wan't be able to enter modify the input values.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is that you put them into a div or span