# Possible to drag Primefaces Inputfield?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

It is possible to drag an primefaces inputfield or someone else ?
On primefaces site there are just panels that i can drag.

My code looks like this:

script.js

```
var xPos;
var yPos;

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#textfeld').draggable({
    drag : function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();

        // Getting the values from the drag item into variables
        xPos = offset.left;
        yPos = offset.top;

        // Setting the text to the drag item
        // $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        // $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);

        document.getElementById('myForm:x').value = xPos;
        document.getElementById('myForm:y').value = yPos;

    }
});

});
```

And my html code:

```
 [...]

<p:inputText id="textfeld"></p:inputText>

<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputHidden value="#{managedBean.x}" id="x" />
    <h:inputHidden value="#{managedBean.y}" id="y" />
    <p:commandButton value="Execute" actionListener="#{managedBean.speichern}" />
</h:form>

<h:outputScript library="js" name="script.js"></h:outputScript>

[...]
```

Comment: So what happens with this code? javascript errors? WW-III? Please elaborate. And check if the id you use is the right one (client-side), I doubt it is

Comment: nothing. No errors

Comment: So `$('#textfeld')` does return the 'inputField'? Tried an `h:inputText`?

Comment: If i put the inputfield into an div element than it works. But that's not what i want. I want just dragging the inputfield

Comment: What you state  is not related to what I asked in my comment...

Comment: <h:inputFiled/> also not working

Comment: Since that renders a plain input, you made your problem way more specific and this is the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895552/jquery-draggable-input-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Draggable Input Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895552/jquery-draggable-input-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this. It works perfectly for me in the PrimeFaces showcase (via a browser developer tool)

```
$("#j_idt87").draggable({ cancel: null });
```

(check the real id via the developer tool, might differ in some cases)

Comment: Hmmm... you accepted the answer (would not have expected this), but does it work for you now? Or did you get errors (considering your other question)

Comment: But it might be that with just  a `p:inputText` plugins are not loaded... Try adding e.g. a dummy `p:tab` or `p:selectOneMenu` or a `<p:draggable for="..." />` or something, but you **must** have gotten an error then)

Comment: they are loaded, see view-source:https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputText.xhtml https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @JasperdeVries : Yes, but there might be some 'templating' that causes this... I don't have an environment available now to check with the code in the question

Comment: Kukeltje: No erros. Have a look at this one http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean by this comment. Why should I have a look at that? What does it tell me? How does this help?